# 中規模アプリケーションのテストデータ作成方法のベストプラクティス教えて下さい。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Model 200個弱
Controller 100個

くらいのアプリケーションを作っています。

テストツールはFactoryGirlとRSpecを使っています。
毎回毎回テストデータをFactoryGirlで作成しているのですが、リレーションもかなり大きく、mock/stub等を用いても、テストデータ作成にかなりの時間がかかってしまいます。

皆様の効率的なテストデータ作成方法を教えて下さい。

Comment: FactoryGirlということはテスト実行時のモデルオブジェクトの作成に時間がかかっているのだと思いますが、現在どのように作成されているのかテストコードの例を書いていただけませんか？またタイトルには「ベストプラクティス」とありますが、あなたが解決したい具体的な問題、例えば「複雑なモデルにFactoryGirlを使うと時間がかかってしまう」といった点に絞ってもいいかもしれないと思いました。

Answer (score 0):

少々主題とずれてしまうかもしれませんが、**テストの実行速度を速くする**という観点でしたら、テストの実行を並列化することも検討してみたらどうでしょうか。ご参考までに並列化するためのライブラリ(gem)としては以下がポピュラーかと思います。

- https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests
- https://github.com/tmm1/test-queue
- https://github.com/cookpad/rrrspec